# Why each block in Deep residual network has two convolutional layers instead of one?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deeplearning4j, deep-residual-networks

[image]

This figure shows a basic block of a residual network. What it has two convolutional layers? What will happen when it has only one convolutional layer?

Answer (score 1):

It should still work with somewhat similar results. There are no problems with skipping only one layer.

See https://openreview.net/forum?id=HkwBEMWCZ
and densenets https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993